# PHP compiled with zlib, but doesn't appear in phpinfo()

Tags: php, php-fpm

I have a program that requires PHP to be configured `--with-zlib`, so I re-ran `./configure`, `make` and `sudo make install` PHP 5.6.15 on my Ubuntu 14.04 server. However, the program still says that PHP wasn't compiled with zlib. `phpinfo()` shows

```
Configure Command: './configure' '--with-mysqli' '--with-pdo-mysql' '--enable-fpm' '--with-mysql'
```

even though I used the `--with-zlib` flag. Running `php -m` lists zlib as a module. My `php.ini` has both `zlib.output_compression = On` and `zlib.output_handler = On`. I've tried restarting PHP-FPM, nginx, and the server itself.

One attempted solution: the first time I tried this, it seems that `./configure` was caching my first configuration *without* zlib. I re-extracted PHP to make sure this wasn't the case, and did everything again. I think it was done correctly this time.

I thought that perhaps my command-line PHP and the PHP running on the webserver were using different configurations, but it doesn't seem that way. My PHP info page shows that I'm using the `php.ini` in `/usr/local/lib`, and `php -i | grep 'php.ini'` shows the same.

Any idea what could be going wrong?

There's a gist of my `config.log` [here](https://gist.github.com/brortao/8501309511314e81f037).

**Solution**:
The issue was that `php-fpm` wasn't running, but instead of notifying me, I assume nginx served up a cached page showing an old `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Is libz-dev installed? Run `./configure --with-mysqli --with-pdo-mysql --enable-fpm --with-mysql --with-zlib > output.txt`, then check output.txt to see if the config script found zlib libraries. If not, you need to do `sudo apt-get install libz-dev`

Comment: It's already installed. `./configure` gives the line `checking for zlib version >= 1.2.0.4... 1.2.8` and if I try to install `libz-dev` anyway, I'm told `Note, selecting 'zlib1g-dev' instead of 'libz-dev'` and  `zlib1g-dev is already the newest version.`

Comment: In some cases, you have to include `--with-libdir=[location] for the configure script to find the libs. In your comment, you did not indicate if there was a "Yes" after  `checking for zlib version >= 1.2.0.4... 1.2.8`.

Comment: There's no `Yes` after `checking for zlib version >= 1.2.0.4... 1.2.8` - I took it to mean that it found a version greater than 1.2.0.4, namely version 1.2.8! I've tried with a few different locations for both `--with-libdir` and `--with-zlib-dir`, such as `/usr`, `/usr/local`, `/usr/share`, `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-57` (because that's where `zlib.h` is) but none of them change the output of `./configure`. Am I trying the wrong directories, or does the error perhaps lie somewhere else?

Comment: I just tried the configure on one of my servers. What you should see is `checking for gzgets in -lz... yes` which is the test the configure script runs to see if libz is working. If you get a `...yes`, then the library was found. I checked my box and see the header in `/usr/include/zlib.h` and the libs in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.a and .so`

Comment: Thank you for checking! I get the same output, and have the same files in the same locations. I think this means that the issue is with my PHP configuration? That's what I'll focus on. I think perhaps PHP isn't loading `php.ini`, I'll check that.

Comment: php.ini does no load zlib, that is done at compile time, and linked into libphp5.so. If you run php -i | grep zlib, can you post the output? I have never had this issue, and have compiled PHP hundreds of times.

Comment: I updated my question with the output of that command. It shows that PHP was configured with `--with-zlib`, but my `phpinfo()` doesn't show this.

Comment: I suspect that you have 2 PHP installations - one as a module and the other as php-fpm (from your compile). The phpinfo() may be coming from some place else that you are expecting.

Comment: It was an annoying problem - php-fpm wasn't starting properly, but instead of telling me, nginx served a cached version - hence the wrong phpinfo information. Thank you for your help!